# Automatic refactoring tools?

Tags: refactoring

Is there a tool that will scan your code and suggest which refactoring to perform, based on duplicate code segments that it finds?

Let's say I'm specifically interested in C#/Java, but I'm open for tools in other languages as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [Teamcity with duplicate finder](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/code_quality.html)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but [Clone Doctor](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Clone/) might work for you.

Comment: CloneDR will show you a parameterized version of the code with the parameter bindings ("arguments") for each duplicated block of code. Making this into a function call or a macro is pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

For Java you have static code review tools to search for violations of a set of chosen rules, with some of the rules covering code duplication. [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) has rules to find duplicate code and duplicate string literals. Another option is the [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)'s *Copy/Paste Detector*.

These tools don't do refactoring themselves, but can help you find code that might need changes.

Answer (score 1):

For Haskell, there's hlint, which proposes concrete refactorings (i.e. the resulting code), which is possible because of referential transparency.

Answer (score 0):

For your need, [Designite](http://www.designite-tools.com) could be a useful tool. This is a software design quality assessment tool. It takes C# code, analyzes it and detects design smells in the code. At the same time, it also provides a few but important OO metrics.