# Automated refactoring tool for java - eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, refactoring, automated-refactoring

Our team wants to adopt a coherent coding style, that has an automated refactor tool to spread the style across the team easily (not in terms of formatting - more like preventing "mistakes" and detecting general pitfalls in the code).

We have those needs:

**- Working well with Eclipse, cross platform (linux/windows)**

**- Manipulate the code without changing its semantics**

**- Configurable (option to enable/disable rules)**

**- Optional: "Short Style" preferred ('v' instead of 'variable', if there is such tool that can do it)**

A bit strict needs - but I'm sure SO community will do it :)

Comment: No we won't. This is off-topic for SO, as requests for off site resources is off-topic.

Comment: Why did this question was upvoted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518972/automatic-refactoring-tools - and mine is not good? Can't see much difference from here.

Comment: Genuinely curious as to how that's still around. Just a heads up, questions asking for recommendations are **off topic**.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew. Personally I have found a lot of great tools based on SO recommendations. But I guess those are the platform rules :\

Comment: also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712133/automatic-refactoring-of-depending-code-after-the-fact

Comment: Just want to know what is the general rule of thumb - because the negative votes doesn't tell anything, and generally makes users less open to ask questions (I really tried to follow the rules here)

Comment: No problem, but we have a separate site for software recommendations: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh... sorry, thanks for the guidance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record I'll mention I was a member of the team developed Spartan refactoring (just a contributor - nothing too fancy), but along the way I've stepped on a few more - all of them are open source:

- **[Spartan Refactoring](https://github.com/SpartanRefactoring/Main)** - cross platform eclipse plugin. Adopts general purpose rules as long as some unique ones representing the Spartan coding style. Completely configurable.
- **[AutoRefactor](http://autorefactor.org/)** - eclipse plugin (I think it's cross platform). Adopts general purpose rules, also includes rules that considered as formatting (like braces eliminations) and also Configurable.
- **[SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org)** - Large toolkit that also includes refactoring tool. Does the job but you also get a bunch of other tools inside (might be good or bad, depending on your needs).

To make the answer complete, have a look at:

[automatic-refactoring-tools](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/3518972/automatic-refactoring-tools)

[automatic-refactoring-tools for java](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/28119760/automatic-code-simplification-via-refactoring)

Comment: I am the author of AutoRefactor. Thanks for mentioning it. It is configurable indeed. But it does not have rules for shortening variable names. It is too subjective to know what the short name should be.